# How to post a message in android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to make a button which will post a message once the button is hit. Here is my main activity.java :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJWts.png)

But I confuse why I cannot choose the onclick option for the button : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p2It.png)

or I dont have to choose the onClick button option again ?
Hope you undestand my question, and here is my video reference from youtube :
"Android Tutorial for Beginners 8 # wrap_content, fill_parent, Password Field and Toast in Android" Uploaded by : ProgrammingKnowledge

Comment: You never call the addListnerOnButton method right? That seems to be the problem. You have to add this in you onCreate: addListnerOnButton();

Comment: Because you must add View parameter to your `addListnerOnButton` method

Comment: Please [edit] and post your code as code, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing wrong in android you can set click listener by two ways
 1. In Java code
 2. In XML

in your example you are doing runtime in java code so it will not show in XML editor

in your case just call your **addListenerOnButton** in **onCreate** it will work

**if you want it in xml**

add onClick function in activity class as below

```
public void buttonClick(View v)
{
  //do what you want 
}
```

then this **buttonClick** will be shown in editor or you can directly add in xml button onClick attribute

```
<Button ...
  android:onClick="buttonClick"/>
```

Comment: how if I make a function of :
public void (View) {

}
will this function will still show up in the onClick attribute ?
@Pavan

Comment: check "if you want it in xml" in answer there is create function buttonClick you can change name if you want that we need to add in xml button onclick attribute

Comment: how if I make a function of : public void addListenerOnButton(View v) { } will this function will still show up in the onClick attribute ?

Comment: what is the function of (View v) in android studio ?

Comment: if you create public function with (View v) it can be used in xml where View v is an instance of view which click is fired in if u set like public void addListenerOnButton(View v) { } you can set it in xml

Comment: should I let the code inside the public function be the same for using with and without (View v ) ?

Comment: if it is normal function you can use without  (View v) but you want to add onclick through xml  (View v ) is mandatory in that case it will better you edit your question according to your problem

Comment: I understand, thank you for the answer and sorry for bothering

Answer (score 0):

Replace the onCreate() method as

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   addListnerOnButton(); //Add this line to your code.
}
```